# Is Heather Mack classified as a Convicted Felon?

Tags: united-states, murder

Convicted Felons have many rights abridged.  Heather Mack was jailed and presumably convicted ***in Indonesia*** of murdering her mother.

https://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/us-woman-bali-suitcase-murder-freed-jail-80847495

1. Is Heather Mack classified as a US Convicted Felon?
   a.  Wherein she would lose rights, such as the right to vote in the US?
2. If yes, what is the nomenclature that captures this notion, wherein a foreign conviction is the basis of a US Felony?

The mother is a Chicago socialite so assume that there relevant state is IL. IANAL

Comment: Do you happen to know which State she will live in? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_disenfranchisement_in_the_United_States#:~:text=As%20of%202018%2C%20most%20U.S.,upon%20completion%20of%20a%20sentence.&text=Felons%20who%20have%20completed%20their,to%20vote%20in%20most%20states.) it depends...

Comment: It would vary for purposes of different statutes. There isn't a uniform definition of this in U.S. law, just as there isn't for most purposes. There are probably at least half a dozen federal law definitions (the one under the Armed Career Criminal Act has been litigated in SCOTUS more than almost any other U.S. statute due to ambiguities in the definition) and probably as many in almost every U.S. state for different purposes. (Notably IL does not deny felons the right to vote unlike many "red" states).

Answer (score -1):

To focus the answer, I will assume that she would return to Illinois. The statute regarding loss of civil rights, [730 ILCS 5/5-5-5](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/fulltext.asp?DocName=073000050K5-5-5), says

> a) Conviction and disposition shall not entail the loss by the
> defendant of any civil rights, except under this Section and Sections
> 29-6 and 29-10 of The Election Code, as now or hereafter amended.

After being released, rights are restored, although the circumstances surrounding a conviction can be considered in making a determination whether a person is of "good moral character". Also, while license rights are generally restored, they are not if

> the authority having jurisdiction of such license rights finds after
> investigation and hearing that restoration is not in the public
> interest.

Federal firearms disability under [18 USC 922](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/922) refers to a [crime punishable by imprisonment for a term exceeding one year](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/921), which is a technical term that excludes Federal or state offenses regarding regulation of business, and (20)(B) "any State offense classified by the laws of the State as a misdemeanor and punishable by a term of imprisonment of two years or less". Under that circumstance (which is not applicable to Mack), conviction can be ignored if civil rights have been restored. [According to DoJ](https://www.justice.gov/archives/jm/criminal-resource-manual-1435-post-conviction-restoration-civil-rights), courts uniformly determine that by reference to the state where the conviction was obtained. Since Indonesia is not a State under the meaning of the term in US law, this condition is not satisfied. So she would be permanently subject to the federal felon-in-possession disability.

Comment: I think you are indicating that Heather Mack IS a felon from the viewpoint of US law?

Comment: No, it's just that "felon-in-possession" is what that situation is called. She is permanently deprived of the right to possess a firearm, under 18 USC 922, which doesn't specifically depend on being a "felon". She was convicted of a crime punishable by imprisonment for a term exceeding one year.

Comment: Whereas, under Illinois law, there are no further disabilities.

Comment: @gatorback this answer is incorrect in its conclusion about federal firearms disability.  The supreme court held in 2004 that "convicted in any court" means "convicted in any US court."  See [Small v. US](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/544/385/).